# flex auto generated file can't be used?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, flex-lexer, lexer

I'm using [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) lexer as a lexer for my compiler project and I have this function to change the lexer input stream as follows:

**.l**

```
void initLexer(string code) {
    lineNumber = 1;
    columnNumber = 0;
    currentStringIndex = 0;
    yy_delete_buffer(YY_CURRENT_BUFFER);
    YY_BUFFER_STATE my_string_buffer = yy_scan_string("sh");
    yy_switch_to_buffer(my_string_buffer);
}
```

and I'm using the following options to generate the suitable routines

```
%option nounput 
%option nomain nodefault
%option noyywrap
%option warn
%option c++
```

after I run the flex lexer tool and I get the auto generated cpp file, I try to build my project but it can't recognize

```
error C2065: 'yy_current_buffer' : undeclared identifier    
error C3861: 'yy_delete_buffer': identifier not found   
error C3861: 'yy_scan_string': identifier not found 
error C3861: 'yy_switch_to_buffer': identifier not found
```

Why?? What should I do??

Answer (score 1):

My solution of this problem - i used flex from MinGW package